# Pandas: How to combine rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```html
'<table border="1" class="dataframe">  <thead>    <tr style="text-align: right;">      <th></th>      <th>CDS_CODE</th>      <th>COUNTY</th>      <th>DISTRICT</th>      <th>SCHOOL</th>      <th>KDGN</th>      <th>GR_1</th>      <th>GR_2</th>      <th>GR_3</th>      <th>GR_4</th>      <th>GR_5</th>      <th>GR_6</th>      <th>GR_7</th>      <th>GR_8</th>      <th>UNGR_ELM</th>      <th>GR_9</th>      <th>GR_10</th>      <th>GR_11</th>      <th>GR_12</th>      <th>UNGR_SEC</th>      <th>ENR_TOTAL</th>      <th>ADULT</th>    </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>    <tr>      <th>0</th>      <td>1611436056865</td>      <td>Alameda</td>      <td>Berkeley Unified</td>      <td>Willard Middle</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>12</td>      <td>16</td>      <td>6</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>34</td>      <td>0</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>1</th>      <td>1611436056865</td>      <td>Alameda</td>      <td>Berkeley Unified</td>      <td>Willard Middle</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>3</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>4</td>      <td>0</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>2</th>      <td>1611436056865</td>      <td>Alameda</td>      <td>Berkeley Unified</td>      <td>Willard Middle</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>23</td>      <td>30</td>      <td>22</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>75</td>      <td>0</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>3</th>      <td>1611436056865</td>      <td>Alameda</td>      <td>Berkeley Unified</td>      <td>Willard Middle</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>3</td>      <td>0</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>4</th>      <td>1611436056865</td>      <td>Alameda</td>      <td>Berkeley Unified</td>      <td>Willard Middle</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>5</td>      <td>15</td>      <td>13</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>0</td>      <td>33</td>      <td>0</td>    </tr>  </tbody></table>'
```

This is the head of my dataframe. I was wondering if there was a way to combine the each grade level together. That is, combine those 5 rows into 1 row. Help??

Comment: So maybe groupby sum ?

Comment: Perhaps its a `groupby sum() or mean()`. As @coldspeed said you are not providing enough information for us to answer.

Comment: im sorry this is my first time. I am trying to add all of the numbers per grade together. For example, the grade 8 column should equal 46. I tried using Pandas.sum(), but there were issues with the first 4 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df.filter(like='GR').sum()
```

Output:

```
GR_1         0
GR_2         0
GR_3         0
GR_4         0
GR_5         0
GR_6        42
GR_7        61
GR_8        46
UNGR_ELM     0
GR_9         0
GR_10        0
GR_11        0
GR_12        0
UNGR_SEC     0
```

Comment: i need enroll total also